# Simplify multiple instances of useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

In my ReactJS code, I need to store multiple variables as separate states like this. Is there any easier way to create them? Because now I use useState function repeatedly.

```
  const [dutyCode, setDutyCode] = useState("");
  const [startTime, handleStartTime] = useState(new Date());
  const [endTime, handleEndTime] = useState(new Date());
  const [activityType, setActivityType] = useState("");
  const [dutyType, setDutyType] = useState("");
```

Comment: For me, it would depend on when the state updates occur. If you're updating them individually, I'd leave it as is and avoid adding complexity to the state management. If they're all updating together, then I'd consider using an approach like described in some of the answers below.

Comment: Actually these variables are form data. Each one is used for different form inputs.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use one state object and destructure it:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    dutyCode: "",
    startTime: new Date(),
    endTime: new Date(),
    activityType: "",
    dutyType: "",
});

const {
    dutyCode,
    startTime,
    endTime,
    activityType,
    dutyType,
} = state;

const updateState = (update) => setState({ ...state, ...update });
```

Answer (score 3):

Easier ways:

1. [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) as docs states:

> useReducer **is usually preferable** to useState **when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values** or when the next state depends on the previous one.

2. Manage a single state:

```
const INITIAL = {
  startTime: "",
  endTime: new Date(),
  dutyCode: "",
  dutyType: new Date(),
};

// Some multi-keyed state
const [state, setState] = useState(INITIAL);

// Example for handling sub-value
const handleDutyCode = (dutyCode) =>
  useState((prev) => ({ ...prev, dutyCode }));
```

Comment: I don't have a complex state logic. I looked at useReducer docs and if I use that, I need to create reducers, actions, etc.

In the solution, again I need to implement handle methods repeatedly.

But thanks in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not have any complex logic to update state, a better approach for you would be to use an object to store multiple states. To simplify your solution, you can write a custom hook that merges the state before updating, so that you don't have to worry about it whenever you are updating state

```
const useMergedState = (initialVal) => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState(initialVal);
   const setMergedValue = useCallback((updatedValue) => {
       setValue(prev => ({
          ...prev,
          ...updatedValue,
       }))
   }, []);
   return [value, setMergedValue] ;
}
```

and use it like

```
const [state, setState] = useMergedState({
  startTime: "",
  endTime: new Date(),
  dutyCode: "",
  dutyType: new Date(),
});
```

and update like

```
setState({startTime: new Date()});
```